# Setting values in Javascript for a vuetify.js v-select not showing in the UI

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a v-select

```
<v-select v-model="defendantCode"
      =label="Defendant Code"
      :items="defendantCodeOptions"
      :loading="defendantCodeIsLoading"
      :filter="customFilter"
      clearable
      multiple
      dense>
</v-select>
```

I pass it an array of items from an ajax call like this

> this.defendantCodeOptions = response.data;

where data is a array like this
{name: "name3", value: 3}, {name: "name4", value: 4}

I want to set the values for the selected items in code behind (Javascript)
and I tried setting them like this

> this.defendantCode = "3,4";

but this doesn't check them off in the UI or place the selected items names
"name3, name4" in the field on screen.

What do I need to do to get these values checked in the drop down and added to the element field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  
  data () {
    return {
      defendantCode: [],
      defendantCodeOptions: []
    }
  },
  
  mounted () {
    this.defendantCodeOptions = [
      {name: 'name1', value: 1},
      {name: 'name2', value: 2},
      {name: 'name3', value: 3},
      {name: 'name4', value: 4}
    ]
    
    this.defendantCode = [3, 4]
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@mdi/font@3.9.97/css/materialdesignicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.0.17/dist/vuetify.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.0.17/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-select
      v-model="defendantCode"
      label="Defendant Code"
      :items="defendantCodeOptions"
      item-text="name"
      clearable
      multiple
      dense
    ></v-select>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

I've made two key changes:

1. `this.defendantCode = [3, 4]`. The value needs to be an array, not a comma-separated string.
2. `item-text="name"`, so that the `name` field will be used as the display text. There was no need to set `item-value` as that defaults to `value`, which already matches what you have in your data.